# Scala.js: How to convert Seq[T] to js.Array[T]

Tags: scala, scala.js

I start working with scala.js, and I want to convert Seq to js.Array. I have this sample code:

```
import scala.scalajs.js
import scala.scalajs.js.annotation._

@JSExportTopLevel("Seqs")
object JsSeqs {

  @JSExport
  def sum(xs: js.Array[Double], ys: js.Array[Double]): js.Array[Double] = {
    val s = Seqs.sum(xs.toSeq, ys.toSeq)
    //how to parse Seq[Double] to js.Array[Double] ???
  }

}

object Seqs {

  def sum(xs: Seq[Double], ys: Seq[Double]): Seq[Double] = {
    xs.zip(ys).map(x => x._1 + x._2)
  }

}
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a way to convert a Seq[Int] to Array[Int]

```
import js.JSConverters._

val scSeq = Seq(1, 2, 3)

// Seq to js.Array -- Copy to js.Array

val jsArray: js.Array[Int] = scSeq.toJSArray
```

For your reference visit this [page](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/types.html).